# Cannot move sites by dragging the hamburger icon on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

I cannot move sites in the "Edit Your Sites" section, because the swipe-from-left-on-screen gesture blocks the hamburger (3-bar) icon.

I'm using Android 5.1 if it matters.

> [image: hamburger icon]

Comment: Hint: you don't need to hold "3 horizontal bars" (or "move button" as you mentioned it) to move it. You can long press and hold on basically anywhere inside the row.

Comment: Oh... then, please specify that more clearly, and/or remove the 3 bars